# RMySQL returns messy codes for utf8 texts

Tags: mysql, r, utf-8, rmysql

SessionInfo is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252
```

I've already set `dbSendQuery(conn, 'SET NAMES utf8')`for the initial connection but I still get messy codes for utf texts. I also run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'`.The results are as follows:
[character set for mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na1AO.png)
My version for MySQL is 5.6.17. Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Comment: Please give an example of the "messy codes"  There are about 5 use cases.

Comment: 1 å¸¸ç†Ÿè‰æ ¹çˆ†æ–™
2          çŽ‹å°å‘†
3       å…«å¦å£¹å§
4 ä¼šåŸŽå¥½å¥½ç”Ÿæ´»
5    ç®¡é—²äº‹é˜Ÿé•¿

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
                                     big5   6  2 '撣貊'
                    binary, utf8, utf8mb4   6  2 '常熟'
                            eucjpms, ujis   6  2 '絽悟'
                                   gb2312   6  2 '甯哥'
                                    euckr  20  8 '躍며넖?疫?녷뼑'
                                      gbk  24  8 '甯哥啛鑹婀鐖嗘枡'
                              cp932, sjis  25  9 '蟶ｸ辭溯画ｹ辷?侭'
```

4.

```
                    binary, utf8, utf8mb4  18  6 '会城好好生活'
                                    euckr  23  9 '鴉싧윃也썲??잍뉵'
                                      gbk  27  9 '浼氬煄濂藉ソ鐢熸椿'
                              cp932, sjis  33 11 '莨壼沁螂ｽ螂ｽ逕滓ｴｻ'
```

Are they recognizable?

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion also applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `&lt;meta charset=UTF-8>`.